# VBA - PasteSpecial not working after using SpecialCells.Copy

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

To sum up, I try to copy some filtered data from a workbook A to a workbook B keeping the formatting of the workbook B.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
With originSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A7:AA" & lastRowOriginSheet)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=projectNumber
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With
End With
destinationSheet.Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The paste special is not working and this is the formatting of the workbook A that is used.

---

Solved:

The problem was that you can't use PasteSpecial in a discontinuous range.

So I went with the solution of Siddharth Rout to go through all the areas of the filtered range:

```
        With originSheet
            .AutoFilterMode = False

            With .Range("A7:AA" & lastRowOriginSheet)
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=projectNumber

                Set filteredRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                '~~> Loop through each area
                For Each area In filteredRange.Areas
                    With destinationSheet
                        '~~> Find Next available row
                        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                        area.Copy
                        destinationSheet.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End With
                Next area
            End With
        End With
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error, or simply not doing it?

Comment: can you also show how you set each sheet to it's workbook ? are they both open when running the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @Jeeped has mentioned is very true that you cannot used `Paste Special` on a filtered range if they are `Non Contiguous`. However there is a way to achieve what you want :)

You have to loop through each `area` of the filtered range and then use `Paste Special` as shown below

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowOriginSheet As Long
    Dim filteredRange As Range, a As Range
    Dim projectNumber As Long

    '~~> I have set these for testing. Change as applicable
    projectNumber = 1
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set destinationSheet = Sheet2
    lastRowOriginSheet = 16

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("A7:AA" & lastRowOriginSheet)
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=projectNumber

            Set filteredRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            '~~> Loop through each area
            For Each a In filteredRange.Areas
                With destinationSheet
                    '~~> Find Next available row
                    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    a.Copy
                    destinationSheet.Range("B" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
            Next a
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**[image]

Answer (score 2):

PasteSpecial does not work on a discontiguous range. If you have one hidden row in among visible rows then you have a discontiguous range. However, due to the nature of a discontiguous range, a straight copy and paste will paste formats and the values from formulas; i.e. it cannot determine how to shift the cell ranges in formulas so it just pastes values.

```
With originSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A7:AA" & lastRowOriginSheet)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=projectNumber
        'you should probably check to ensure you have visible cells before trying to copy them
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination:=destinationSheet.Range("B4")
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Does the `...Range("B4")` work properly here? As I noted in my Edit, when I did `Range("B4").Value = Range("H2:K20").Value`, it only put a single value in `B4`, and didn't do the remaining values.

Comment: If you do a value transfer you have to match the size of the destination range with the source range; you can use just the upper-left corner cell in a copy & paste.

Comment: ++ `PasteSpecial does not work on a discontiguous range.` True that.

Comment: @Jeeped - Ah, I didn't know that (about the Value transfer not doing the whole range, but copy/paste does).  Good to know!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Instead of doing `PasteSpecial`, since you just need values, you can set the ranges equal to eachother.

```
Dim copyRng As Range
With originSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A7:AA" & lastRowOriginSheet)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=projectNumber
        Set copyRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
End With
' destinationSheet.Range("B4").Value = copyRng.Value
With destinationSheet
    .Range(.Cells(4, 2), .Cells(4 + copyRng.Rows.Count - 1, 2 + copyRng.Columns.Count - 1)).Value = copyRng.Value
End With
```

(this is assuming your worksheet and lastRow and projectNumber are all declared properly and working).

Edited because if you just do `Range("B4").Value = Range("A1:Z100").Value`, it's only going to put the first value in your copied range in the cell. You need to expand the destination range to be the size of the copy range.

Comment: Does that overlook the .Areas issue with a discontiguous range?

Comment: @Jeeped - Good thinking, I'm not sure actually...Edit: Nope - if there are visible rows, then hidden rows, then visible, then hidden, then.... it seems to just grab the first non-hidden rows and ignores the others.